# SICP exercise 1.15 Is operands evaluated prior to operators?

Tags: scheme, evaluation, sicp

You can see the question [here](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/1_002e2.xhtml#g_t1_002e2_002e3)

The code used is

```
(define (cube x) (* x x x)) 
(define (p x) (- (* 3 x) (* 4 (cube x)))) 
(define (sine angle)
(if (not (> (abs angle) 0.1)) 
    angle 
    (p (sine (/ angle 3.0)))))
```

So I understand what the code is doing, but I have a question on part a. *How many times is the procedure p applied when (sine 12.15) is evaluated?*
I googled and most answers look like this:

```
 (sine 12.15) 
 (p (sine 4.05)) 
 (p (p (sine 1.35))) 
 (p (p (p (sine 0.45))))
 (p (p (p (p (sine 0.15))))) 
 (p (p (p (p (p (sine 0.05)))))) 
 (p (p (p (p (p 0.05)))))
```

I also understand what the answers are saying, but my question is, why is the procedure *p* not evaluated first? More specifically, when the interpreter reaches the second line, `(p(sine 4.05))`, why doesn't it first evaluate as `(- (* 3 (sine 4.05)) (* 4 (cube (sine 4.05))))` and take this result to do the recursion?

This is definitely a messier approach, and I believe the answer to my question comes down to how "Applicative Order" is performed. Does this question suggest that when evaluating, the interpreter will first evaluate the operands, then the operators?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this form:

```
(+ 1 2 (- 3 1))
```

In applicative order, since there are no special forms involved all the 4 parts, the variable `+`, the form `(- 3 1)`, and the two constants `1` and `2` needs to be evaluated **before** whatever is the result of evaluating `+` can be applied.

The order of evaluation is deliberately left out of the language and thus the implementation can decide what is the best order for each call place. In reality most scheme implementations does a left to right. I think MIT Scheme does a strict right to left. The only time you actually notice this is if any of the expressions in a form has side effects.

So if we look at your form:

```
(p (sine 4.05))
```

What must be finished evaluated before `(p ...)` can be applied? Well `(sine 4.05)` of course. Also notice that in your naive expansion of `p` first you actually duplicated `(sine 4.05)` which would have complicated your further expansion quite a bit. In lazy languages the expression isn't copied but simply replaced with a promise that would remember the calculated value once computed.

Answer (score 0):

The *variable* `p` might well be evaluated first. Since

```
(define (p x) (- (* 3 x) (* 4 (cube x))))
```

is the same as

```
(define p 
  (lambda (x) (- (* 3 x) (* 4 (cube x)))))
```

evaluating `p` produces the value of the lambda form, which is the function to be called.

Then when the argument's value is also found, that procedure is applied to that argument value, and *at that point* the procedure's body is entered:

```
((lambda (x) (- (* 3 x) (* 4 (cube x))))
 (sine 4.05))
=
(- (* 3 <s405>) (* 4 (cube <s405>)))
=
...
```

where `<s405>` indicates the actual value of `(sine 4.05)`, calculated recursively.